# AttributeError when I return class

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, sanic

Использую `sanic` для моей API, и peewe как `ORM`
И хочу создать хелпер клас которий будет возрощать json ответ, но вот такая вот ошибка, подскажите в какую сторону смотреть.

```
AttributeError: 'JsonResponse' object has no attribute 'all_records'
```

`get` method in controller

```
from sanic.response import json
from sanic.views import HTTPMethodView

from models.project import Project
from helpers.json import JsonResponse


class ProjectListResource(HTTPMethodView):
    def get(self, resp):
        projects = Project().select().dicts()
        return JsonResponse(projects, all_records=True)
```

и `helper` class

```
from sanic.response import json

class JsonResponse:
    def __init__(self, model, all_records=None):
        self.model = self._model_query(model)
        self.all_records = all_records

    def _model_query(self, model):
        if self.all_records:
            records = json({model: list(model)})
        else:
            records = {}

        return records
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе JsonResponse в методе инициализации вы первой строчкой вызываете метод _model_query, который обращается к self.all_records. Однако, к этому моменту ещё не существует self.all_records - оно будет создано только в следующей строчке метода инициализации.

Вам нужно переписать метод инициализации так:

```
def __init__(self, model, all_records=None):
        self.all_records = all_records           # Сначала эта строка
        self.model = self._model_query(model)    # И только потом эта
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. Что-то не сразу посмотрел:) иногда нужно быть внимательней.